# Library callback result via get API nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-imap

I'm trying to fetch all the mails from an inbox in nodejs and i'm using this library [IMAP](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), I was successful in getting all the mails in my local machine, now I want to provide it as an get API, so i'm using express server and created a get url but the problem is that the IMAP library has its own callback mentioned below:

```
imap.once('end', function() {
    console.log('Connection ended');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({data: inboxesVals});
});
```

And I don't know if we can put the whole library code including callback above in that GET api function block, so how do I wait for the IMAP library to fetch the results and return the response?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to solve it by my own, here's what I did (in case anybody else faces the same problem).
Basic info:
Server: Ubuntu with express server
Server Stack: nodeJs with Mustache (handlebars) 
Frontend: bootstrap, angular

I had to make an get API but that IMAP library has its own events based on which the result is returned, so simply using request/response in express I did following:

```
app.get('/getBox', (req, res) => {res.send({status: true});});
```

so sending response when imap end event is triggered was the only thing that worked.